# Zend Date -- day difference

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-date

I have the below line of codes

```
$day1 = new Zend_Date('2010-03-01', 'YYYY-mm-dd');
$day2 = new Zend_Date('2010-03-05', 'YYYY-mm-dd');
$dateDiff = $day2->getDate()->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP) - $day1->getDate()->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
$days = floor((($dateDiff / 60) / 60) / 24);
return  $days;
```

this will return 4

But if gave

```
$day1 = new Zend_Date('2010-02-28', 'YYYY-mm-dd');
$day2 = new Zend_Date('2010-03-01', 'YYYY-mm-dd');
$dateDiff = $day2->getDate()->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP) - $day1->getDate()->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
$days = floor((($dateDiff / 60) / 60) / 24);
return  $days;
```

it will return -27 .. how will i get right answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$firstDay = new Zend_Date('2010-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
$lastDay = new Zend_Date('2010-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
$diff = $lastDay->sub($firstDay)->toValue();
$days = ceil($diff/60/60/24) +1;
```

return  $days;

this gives the right answer

Answer (score 8):

I believe the problem is in your part string. Try **YYYY-MM-dd** instead.

```
$day1 = new Zend_Date('2010-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
$day2 = new Zend_Date('2010-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
echo $day2->sub($day1)->toString(Zend_Date::DAY);
```

Comment: Beware 'YYYY' is the ISO Year. Use 'yyyy' for the year.

Comment: Zend Framework Date::sub() returns a difference in seconds and not an object toString won't work.

Comment: Looking at the date code right now and sub() returns $this at the end (which is a Zend_Date object). This is with version 1.11 of the zend framework.

Comment: This code will not work as expected if the difference is bigger than one month

Comment: This approach will modify the `day2` Object, which may not be desired, considering OP only asked for a comparison in days. I, for one, would want to avoid modifying Objects as they may be needed with the original date later on.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $cerimonia = new Zend_Date('your date here');
    $days = $cerimonia->sub(Zend_Date::now());
    $days = round($days/86400)+1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've extended `Zend_Date` for my own convenience functions.  My solution is similar to Nisanth's, with some key differences:

1. calculate the beginning of the day for both days before comparing
2. use `round()` instead of `ceil()`
3. do not add `1` to the result

Example code:

```
class My_Date extends Zend_Date
{
    public static function now($locale = null)
    {
        return new My_Date(time(), self::TIMESTAMP, $locale);
    }

    /**
     * set to the first second of current day
     */
    public function setDayStart()
    {
        return $this->setHour(0)->setMinute(0)->setSecond(0);
    }

    /**
     * get the first second of current day
     */
    public function getDayStart()
    {
        $clone = clone $this;
        return $clone->setDayStart();
    }

    /**
     * get count of days between dates, ignores time values
     */
    public function getDaysBetween($date)
    {
        // 86400 seconds/day = 24 hours/day * 60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute
        // rounding takes care of time changes
        return round($date->getDayStart()->sub(
            $this->getDayStart()
        )->toValue() / 86400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If $date is a Zend_Date object you can use the following:

```
if ($date->isEarlier(Zend_Date::now()->subDay(2)){
    [...]
}
```

or the other subXxx functions of the Zend_Date object.

Comment: Loved your approach. I used with ->isLater, that is also available (for other purpose, of course).

Answer (score 0):

number of days between date of registration (later) and date of purchase (before)

```
// $datePurchase instanceof Zend_Date
// $dateRegistration instanceof Zend_Date
if($datePurchase && $dateRegistration) {
   $diff = $dateRegistration->sub($datePurchase)->toValue();
   $days = ceil($diff/60/60/24)+1;
 }
```