# Calculating difference between 2 Zend_Date objects

Tags: php, zend-framework, date, time, zend-date

I have 2 Zend_Date objects:

```
$d1 = new Zend_Date('2011-11-14 12:20:30');
$d2 = new Zend_Date('2012-11-16 13:40:10');
```

And I need to calculate difference. My output should be like this:

```
Years: 1, Months: 0, Days: 2, Hours: 1, Minutes: 19, Seconds: 40
```

I can do it with `DateTime` class and `diff` method. But my hoster has PHP version < 5.3. Can you help me how can I do it in Zend? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to calculate a difference between two Zend_Date objects, in months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032101/how-to-calculate-a-difference-between-two-zend-date-objects-in-months)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513830/zend-date-day-difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no implemented function to calculate the difference between two dates, unfortunately.

```
<?php
$diff = $d2->sub($d1)->toValue();
$days = floor($diff/60/60/24);
$months = floor($diff/60/60/24/30);
?>
```

This should help you get the variables you need.

Answer (score -3):

You can get the timestamp of Zend_Date objects by `$date->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP)`. Then you can work with the normal PHP-functions to format your date like described [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)