# Zend _date difference php error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I used the below code for finding the difference in days for two dates :

```
   1 $startDate = new Zend_Date('2010-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
   2 $lastDate  = new Zend_Date('2010-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
   3 $diff = $lastDate->sub($startDate)->toValue();
   4 $days = ceil($diff/60/60/24) +1;
```

The 3rd line in php shows me an error :

> Expected an operand but found 
>   Refs:[Zend Date -- day difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513830/zend-date-day-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in 3rd line

```
$diff = $lastDate->sub($startDate)->toString(Zend_Date::DAY);
```

that solve your problem.